# Using DISTINCT, SUBSTR and ORDER BY simultaneously

Tags: sql, oracle

I am making Oracle queries in BusinessObjects and I can't use these three keywords at the same time : DISTINCT, SUBSTR and ORDER BY.

It is possible to use DISTINCT **and** ORDER BY **or** DISTINCT **and** SUBSTR, but not all these three together.

The error returned is "ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression".

This works :

```
SELECT
DISTINCT HPD_HELP_DESK.Product_Name
FROM
HPD_HELP_DESK
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(HPD_HELP_DESK.Product_Name, '^[A-Z]{2}[A-Z]? -')
ORDER BY HPD_HELP_DESK.Product_Name
```

This works too :

```
SELECT
DISTINCT SUBSTR(HPD_HELP_DESK.Product_Name, 1, 3)
FROM
HPD_HELP_DESK
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(HPD_HELP_DESK.Product_Name, '^[A-Z]{2}[A-Z]? -')
```

Can you please tell me what to write to make it work ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add alias to `SUBSTR` and use in `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(HPD_HELP_DESK.Product_Name, 1, 3) AS result
FROM HPD_HELP_DESK
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(HPD_HELP_DESK.Product_Name, '^[A-Z]{2}[A-Z]? -')
ORDER BY result;
```

or:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(HPD_HELP_DESK.Product_Name, 1, 3)
FROM HPD_HELP_DESK
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(HPD_HELP_DESK.Product_Name, '^[A-Z]{2}[A-Z]? -')
ORDER BY SUBSTR(HPD_HELP_DESK.Product_Name, 1, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the column number:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(HPD_HELP_DESK.Product_Name, 1, 3) 
FROM HPD_HELP_DESK
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(HPD_HELP_DESK.Product_Name, '^[A-Z]{2}[A-Z]? -')
ORDER BY 1
```